# PHP serial number on fetched database rows

Tags: php, serialization, auto-increment, post-increment

I am working on a project that fetches certain records from a database and displays in a table. The number of records (rows) fetched depends on my given conditions. All these work just fine for me.

My challenge is that I would like to display a serial number column (SN) with result set numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. depending on how many rows were found. Though my database has the `id` column which is auto_incremented during the `INSERT` command, however, if I fetch this `id` column values (which is working fine for me), it will give me those stored number values but not 1, 2, 3, etc. The code below is what I am using which works fine for me, just to populate the SN column with 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. down the column.

```
$output ="SELECT * FROM guest_tb where((arrival_day='$arrival_day') and (arrival_month='$arrival_month') and (arrival_year='$arrival_year')) order by names asc";
$query=mysql_query($output);
//$cnt=mysql_num_rows($query);

while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?> <tr>  
<td><div align="center" class="style61">  
<div align="left"><?php // Here comes the code for serial number </div></div></td>
<td><div align="center" class="style61">  
<div align="left"><?php echo $result['names']; if(($result['room_number'])!=="") {echo " (Room ".$result['room_number'].")";} ?></div>  
  </div></td>  
  <td><div align="center" class="style61"><?php echo   number_format($result['room_rate'],0,',',',')." NGN" //echo ", ". $result['Website'];?></div>  
      <div align="center"></div></td>  
  <td><div align="right" class="style61"><?php echo   number_format($result['amount_paid'],0,',',',')." NGN";?></div></td>  
  <td align="center"><div align="center" class="style61"><?php echo $result['remark'];?></div>     </td>
</tr>
<?php }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i can understand..

maintain a counter inside the while loop. for the next pages (if you are having pagination), set the value of the this counter as

counter = (currentpage * number of items per page) + 1

..hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks friends. I found an answer to my challenge in this way:

First of all I defined a counter that counts the number of rows fetched: '$cnt'

$output ="SELECT * FROM guest_tb where((arrival_day='$arrival_day') and (arrival_month='$arrival_month') and (arrival_year='$arrival_year')) order by names asc";
$query=mysql_query($output);
$cnt=mysql_num_rows($query);

Then, initialized a variable $i=1, after which in the while loop, I gave 2 conditions for the while loop: while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query) and $i<=$cnt)

So, the first condition of the while loop I later used it to fetch records from the database and display in a table.

Finally, in the displayed table, I made 'SN' column and used this code to create the serial number (what I was looking for)... and the serial numbering depends on the number of records fetched, that is, if there are 3 records fetched from database, serial number will start from 1 and stop at 3 - the value of the $cnt. Here is the simple code:

echo $i."
";
$i++;

That's all it is. Hope one can find this useful.